# How to check if float has only 2 decimal places not equal to 0

Tags: objective-c, slider, decimal

I have NSSlider, and I rect to it's changes. But I want my action to work only if slider's float value is for example `2.230000` or `3.410000`.

```
if (floatValue is y.xx0000) {
    doSomething;
}
```

I mean I want to do some action only if my float has only 2 decimal places not equal to 0. How could I do it?

Answer (score 4):

The *only* float values that have only two non-zero fractional digits are numbers of the form n.00, n.25, n.50, or n.75.  All other values have more than two non-zero fractional digits.  Your example, 3.41, for example, isn't really "3.41".  Instead it's:

```
3.410000000000000142108547152020037174224853515625
```

and "2.23" is actually:

```
2.229999999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875
```

So what are you really trying to do?

Comment: If for example my slider bounds are from `1.5` to `1.6` I want to react to only these values:
`1.50, 1.51, 1.52, 1.53, 1.54, 1.55, 1.56, 1.57, 1.58, 1.59, 1.60` and all others (for example `1.510000000025251000125`) I want to be ignored.

Comment: Oh, that's easy: there are NO float values between 1.5 and 1.6 that **only** have two digits after the decimal place.  That is what Stephen is saying in this answer.  That is how floats work...

Comment: and if you imagine that it is `1.50000000000000000000000` then the float value exist? Or it cant have only one or two numbers bigger than 0 after comma?

Comment: @JuliusPetraška: `1.5` is exactly 1.5, because it is a dyadic rational number (3/2).

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late to this game, but I found this question while searching for something similar.
It sounds to me like what you're trying to do is to round the value that the slider is set to to 2 decimal places. That way the thing and/or calculation you're trying to configure with the slider, will always work as though it only works for exact 2 decimal values.

Alternatively, you could check how large the distance is between your float value, and the value rounded to 2 decimal places. And then put a threshold of for example 0.005 for when it's to far away.